# jQuery UI draggable/droppable overflow hidden

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

This seems like a bit of a common issue, but I can't think of a solution at all for some reason.

I'm building a site that requires drag/drop functionality. However, there are multiple items within sliders. Obviously the slider has `overflow hidden` and `relative positioning` within it so that the slide can work.

The combination of these two attributes means that when an image is dragged from the div, it is cut off by the overflow. If there is no relative positioning, then the overflow doesn't affect the dragged element.

However, I'm pretty sure every slider/swiper will have relative positioning as well as overflow hidden as they need that to work properly.

But, can anyone think of a solution?

[Here's a reduced test case for the site](http://cdpn.io/KphLw). I haven't included the slider js, but the basic css with position/overflow is there to show the issue.

For those that wish to check the code, the slider I'm using is [swipe.js](http://swipejs.com/).

Removing the position from `.items` `.item` and `.site-wrap` will show you how the drag/drop still works with `overflow: hidden`.

[EDIT]

I noticed that jQuery UI adds a class to an element once it starts to get dragged. I started to think if there's a way to latch onto that to alter the overflow value of that particular element. but changing it to `overflow: none` didn't seem to do anything, the issue seems to be with the two parent elements, which of course can't be altered as users can drag/drop multiple items.

Answer (score 0):

Try using draggable's [appendTo](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-appendTo) option in your call to draggable.

```
$( ".big-item" ).draggable({ 
    snap: ".big-dropzone",
    revert: "invalid", 
    helper: "clone", 
    opacity: 1,
    cursor: "move",
    appendTo: ".big-dropzone"
});
```

Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/dalehille/pen/gbWVPK) fork of your example